# Two factor authentication using identity server 4

Tags: identityserver4

How to implement a two factor authentication using Identity Server 4? The token end point returns a token with a username and password / client credentials.
Can we customize those end points?

Both the methods as per the sample does not allow to customize the end point:

```
>     var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.client", "secret");
>     var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("brockallen@gmail.com",
> "Pass123$", "api1");
```

Is it possible to achieve 2 factor authentication using either asp.net identity Or EF Core implementation?

Comment: You have to hit an authorize endpoint for MFA.  It passes back an authorization code that you pass into the token endpoint.  It typically handles both authentications (it asks for user/password, then asks to input a code from a text/phone).  To the authorize endpoint, you pass "response_type=code&response_mode=query" ... When you get the authorization code back, you pass "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + [code]).  I don't believe it's possible to do MFA directly through the token endpoint without getting an auth code from the auth endpoint first.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Do you have any reference sample for the same.

Comment: It's not exact (I use Azure), but OAuth is OAuth - you'll just need to figure out the differences between Azure and IdentityServer.  Here is a question I asked and answered when I was looking into it.  I looked at IdentityServer docs, and the Oauth part appears identical... So, not exact but maybe it can help you get there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954137/azure-mfa-in-cordova-app-that-uses-jwt-oauth-2-0-tokens

Comment: 2FA wont work with RO flow, and you can make your own grants if you want but I highly discourage you from doing 2FA with Resource Owner grant.

Comment: @Lutando What do you suggest is the best way when we go for 2FA?

Comment: Well I would say that 2FA would work with a custom grant that looks like resource owner flow, however I would prefer to do 2FA ontop of something like implicit or hybrid flow.

Comment: Thanks @Lutando Getting a hang of it better now.

Answer (score 8):

This shouldn't be a problem at all. When a user is redirected to the Identity Server for login in, if 2FA is enabled then he/she would have to enter the authenticator's code before the Identity Server returns the response back. I have created a repository and [blog post series](https://github.com/chsakell/aspnet-core-identity)  that explain in detail the related concepts. In the [AccountController](https://github.com/chsakell/aspnet-core-identity/blob/master/IdentityServer/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L104-L139) of the IdentityServer you have to check if 2FA is enabled and ask the user to proceed by providing an authenticator code before returning the response.

```cs
var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, true,
    lockoutOnFailure: false);

if (signInResult.RequiresTwoFactor)
{
    result.Status = Status.Success;
    result.Message = "Enter the code generated by your authenticator app";
    result.Data = new {requires2FA = true};
    return result;
}
```

You will also need a [TwoFactorAuthenticationController](https://github.com/chsakell/aspnet-core-identity/blob/master/AspNetCoreIdentity/Controllers/TwoFactorAuthenticationController.cs#L246-L300) that supports all the 2FA tasks *(enable/disable 2FA, sign in with authenticator code/recovery tokens, reset authenticator, etc...)*